# What are the requirements to compile CUDA programs with an NVIDIA GeForce gt 520 graphic card in Windows 7

Tags: cuda

I already know c programming. I am learning to write CUDA codes, but don't know which free compiler to use....

Answer (score 1):

CUDA code should be compiled with NVIDIA's compiler - nvcc. You can download it from their website, together with the necessary toolkit libraries.

---

As Robert suggested in the comment --- this is a good starting point: http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda

Comment: [This is a good starting point](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda), which includes the necessary toolkit, code samples, as well as links to documentation, webinars, etc.